# C++ fstream error

Tags: c++, file-io

I learning c++, started learning File Handling today. but getting a error when runinng this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream.h>

using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        fstream file;
        file.open("test.txt",ios::in|ios::out)

        file.close();

        return 0;
    }
```

Gets error

```
Cannot open include file: 'fstream.h': No such file or directory
```

Whats Wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Change your include to:

```
#include <fstream>
```

It is a standard library, and you are trying to point it to a non existing header file.

Answer (score 4):

Missing semicolon:

```
 file.open("test.txt",ios::in|ios::out)
```

shoud be:

```
 file.open("test.txt",ios::in|ios::out);
```

Answer (score 2):

For standard C++ includes, don't use the .h extension:

```
#include <fstream>
```